# How to make a selectable card component accessible regarding WCAG with React, JS, CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, wcag

Can someone please help me understand how I can make this problem accessible for keyboard users and screen reader users?

What I want to achieve:

1. List of cards which represents different values from a form (a type of label - value, but with more data)
2. When you click one of the cards in the list, you open a dialog and get a new list, which is a list of cards with more information than a dropdown. This last list should have the same propperties as a dropdown or a radio button group, the possibility to select an option.

Why?
Because this will give the user even more information than regular dropdown with label-value.

I guess I have to achieve all of these points (but how?), and maybe more points that I have not thought about, and I hope you assist me here.

For the **first** tyoe of list:

- Use `ul` and `li`
- Make it possible to tab and shift + tab and focus on with `tabindex="0"`
- Handle Enter and Space with onKeyDown to select and open the modal
- Style CSS for `hover`, `focus`, `active`, `disable`

For the **second** type of list:

- Use `ul` and `li`
- Make it possible to tab and shift + tab and focus on with `tabindex="0"`
- Maybe use `role="listbox"` on the outer list and `role="option"` on the cards?
- Make it possible to navigate with arrows with onKeyDown here as well
- Style CSS for `hover`, `focus`, `active`, `disable`
- Handle Enter and Space with onKeyDown to select and possible close the modal

How do I set a div to `active`? Is it something like you do for `focus`, `element.focus()`?
How should a screen reader read this out loud? If I style the cards with divs and `display: flex`, then it would be read out very divided.
I wonder what more I should think about?

Thank you for all your input!

[[image: First list of selectable cards, probably in an ul]]
[image: Another list of selectable cards, but more like an dropdown / radio button group than a ul-list]

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the various [accessible design patterns](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/) first and see which one may fit your situation.